# Difference between byte ptr and word ptr

Tags: assembly, x86-16, pointers

I saw the following question on a test paper,

### Question

```
VarM DWORD ABBF01598h
```

Give the contents of registers `al`, `bx`, and `dl` after the execution of

1. `mov al, byte ptr VarM + 1`
2. `mov bx, word ptr VarM + 2`
3. `mov dl, byte ptr VarM + 3`

Now I know word ptr and byte ptr by definitions but I am unable to pickup the concept of them.

### According to me

1. `al = b`
2. `bx = 0`
3. `dl = F`

Please help me out in understanding these. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the cases you're looking at, the `byte ptr` and `word ptr` don't accomplish much. While harmless, the assembler already "knows" that `al` and `dl` are byte-sized, and that `bx` is word-sized.

You need something like `byte ptr` when (for example) you move an immediate value to an indirect address:

```
mov bx, some offset
mov [bx], 1
```

This won't normally be allowed -- the assembler has no way to know whether you want the `1` written into a byte, a word, a double-word, possibly a quad-word, or what. You fix it by using a size specification:

```
mov byte ptr [bx], 1  ; write 1 into a byte
mov word ptr [bx], 1  ; write 1 into a word
mov dword ptr [bx], 1 ; write 1 into a dword
```

You *can* get the assembler to accept the version without a (direct) size specification:

```
mov bx, some_offset
assume bx: ptr byte

mov [bx], 1   ; Thanks to the `assume`, this means `byte ptr [bx]`
```

Edit: (mostly to reply to @NikolaiNFettisov). Try this quick test:

```
#include <iostream>

int test() { 
    char bytes[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

    _asm mov eax, dword ptr bytes + 1
}

int main() {
    std::cout << std::hex << test();
    return 0;
}
```

The result I get is:

```
5040302
```

Indicating that even though I've told it `dword ptr`, it's adding only 1 to the address, not 4. Of course, somebody writing a different assembler *could* do it differently, if they chose.

Comment: Not sure, but isn't `byte ptr VarM + 1` equal `VarM + 1`, but `word ptr VarM + 2` equal `VarM + 4`, like in C?

Answer (score 1):

Normally used to indicate to the assembler what instruction you are trying to encode.  If you look at the instruction set (encoding) it should be more obvious.  In general it means you are referring to an 8 bit item or 16 bit item (or 32 bit item, etc).  if you want to store the constant #1 in memory for example, do you want to store it as a byte or a word?  There are different encodings for each but if you dont specify the assembler wont know what encoding to use.