# 8086 MOV instruction error while using a constant value and memory location as operands,

Tags: x86-16, mov

I was trying to use the instruction `MOV [SI],00H` in 8086 assembly language. But the masm assembler gave me an error saying: `Operand must have size`. I am unable to understand the reason behind it.

Also, is the syntax even allowed? Because while comparing a memory location's content with a constant value, I got the same error again. I'm new to 8086 programming, so it's hard to figure out.

Comment: duplicate:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10413759/difference-between-byte-ptr-and-word-ptr

Answer (score 4):

MASM complains because it can not know what kind of data is at the address pointed at by the SI register. Is it a byte or a word ?
That's why you have to provide a size tag.

```
mov byte ptr [si], 0
```

or

```
mov word ptr [si], 0
```